# What is in the reCaptcha script the 'is_valid' text? Is it an array key?

Tags: php, recaptcha

In the reCaptcha script you'll find this piece of code:

```
$recaptcha_response->is_valid = false;
```

I wonder what the `->` does/means.
Is it an alternative way to assign an key (with a value) to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$recaptcha_response` is an instance of a object.

`is_valid` is a public property of the object.

`$recaptcha_response-> = false` assign a boolean values (false) at the property `is_valid`.

Later you can use it like 
`if ($recaptcha_response->is_valid)`//Do something

Comment: Can anybody recommend me a tutorial about objects in php?

Answer (score 0):

That's actually php's object notation, you should see the object `$recaptcha_response` declared somewhere else in the script.  It is calling the `is_valid` method of that object/class.

Comment: `is_valid` is not a function (better to call it method). Is a property.

Comment: Can anybody recommend me a tutorial about objects in php?